# ContractDescription 'IService1' has zero operations

Tags: c#, wcf

This is my first Wcf Services.With Wcf service we should be able to query the view in the Oracle Database.I created IService1 as below where request_id,room,jrs_no,submitdate are the fields in the View

```
namespace SampleSelectService
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    string GetData( string room);
}
[DataContract]
public class GTSDetails
{
    int request_id;
    string room = string.Empty;
    int jrs_no ;
    DateTime submitdate;

    [DataMember]

    public int REQUEST_ID
    {
        get { return request_id; }
        set { request_id = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string ROOM
    {
        get { return room; }
        set { room = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int JRS_NO
    {
        get { return jrs_no; }
        set { jrs_no = value; }
    }
   [DataMember]
    public DateTime SUBMITDATE
    {
        get { return submitdate; }
        set { submitdate = value; }
    }}}
```

Then created the Service1.cs as below

```
namespace SampleSelectService
 {     public class Service1 : IService1
   {
    public string GetData(string ROOM)
    {
       List<OracleParameter> prms = new List<OracleParameter>();
        prms.Add(new OracleParameter("ROOM", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ROOM, ParameterDirection.Input));
        using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=A;PASSWORD=B;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=D"))
        {
            DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
            var strQuery = @"SELECT * from LIMS_SAMPLE_RESULTS_VW where ROOM = :ROOM";
            OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn);
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand);
            DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(selectResults);
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectResults);
           }}}}
```

When in debugging I tried to call the service `http://localhost:24379/Service1.svc`. It throws the error like
[image]

Comment: Add the operationcontract attribute above the getData method

Answer (score 0):

In order to expose the GetData method in a WCF application, you need to define the ***operationcontract*** attribute above the method

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
   [OperationContract]
   string GetData( string room);
}
```